Singleton class with thread safety
I am working in a project where I have to show the progress of an asynchronous process. To get the progress, I am using a progress class:
from flask import jsonify
import threading

class Progress:
    _instance = None
    _lock = threading.Lock()

    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls._instance:
            with cls._lock:
                if not cls._instance:
                    cls._instance = super(Progress, cls).__new__(cls)
                    cls._instance.progress = {
                        "commit_id": None,
                        "status": "idle",
                        "last_run": {
                            "commit_id": None,
                            "status": None
                        }
                    }
        return cls._instance

    def update_commit_id(self, commit_id):
        self.progress["commit_id"] = commit_id

    def update_status(self, status):
        self.progress["status"] = status

    def update_last_run(self, status):
        self.progress["last_run"] = {
            "commit_id": self.progress["commit_id"],
            "status": status
        }

    def log_progress(self):
        return jsonify(self.progress), 200

I am accessing this progress in the main thread as:
from flask import jsonify

from pebble import ProcessPool

from app.utils.progress import Progress
from app.utils.proc import proc

pool = ProcessPool(max_workers=1)

current_task = None
prog = Progress()
p = process()

def process():
    global prog, current_task
    try:
        p.start_process()
        prog.update_status("idle")
        prog.update_last_run("successful")
    except Exception as e:
        prog.update_status("idle")
        prog.update_last_run("failed")

@app.route("/start", methods=["POST"])
def start():
    global current_task
    try:
        if current_task and not current_task.done():
            current_task.cancel()
            if current_task.cancelled():
                prog.update_last_run("aborted")
                current_task = None
            else:
                return jsonify({'message': "Error"}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'message': "Error "}), 500
    
    prog.update_status("in progress")

    current_task = pool.schedule(process)
    
    return jsonify({'message': "Started"}), 200

@app.route("/progress", methods=["GET"])
def embedding_progress():
    return prog.log_progress()

I am also accessing it from a function within the
Proc class as:
from app.utils.progress import Progress 
@staticmethod
    def some_method():
        progress = Progress()
        progress.update_commit_id("1234")

When I am running the code and hitting the /start endpoint, it returns 200 response and changes the status to "in progress". But when the thread runs some_method, the status of it's progress is null.I want all the threads in the thread pool to access the same instance of the singleton class.
I have tried to debug and found that every thread is creating it's own instance of progress, but if i access the progress from different classes within the same thread execution, the singleton class works properly. I have tried using threadlock, but I am not able to achieve the desired results
